# How can I test the relevance between two interaction effects from two repeated measures ANOVAs?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, anova, repeated-measures, interaction

To assess the impact of temperature and humidity on CPU performance, we conducted an experiment where we manipulated temperature and humidity levels. There were two within-subjects variables in the experiment: temperature (with high and low levels) and humidity (with high, medium, and low levels). We measured the performance of massive CPUs using two metrics: response speed and average speed of long-term calculations.

Then we conducted two repeated measures ANOVAs (2x3) with response speed and average speed of long-term calculations as dependent variables. Both ANOVAs revealed significant interaction effects.

I want to test to what extent these two indicators (response speed and average speed of long-term calculations) can be used interchangeably in detecting the interaction effects between temperature and humidity , in order to draw the conclusion that future research can use only one indicator to detect the interaction effect because it can predict the other indicator to a large extent.

How can I do this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts.

First, with two separate outcomes, this might best be handled by  "[multivariate ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_analysis_of_variance)," in which "multivariate" means "multiple outcomes." This [Penn State course](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat505/lesson/8) explains what's involved. Although the point estimates for each outcome's associations with predictors will be the same as for your separate models, multivariate analysis has the advantage of directly evaluating outcome correlations, which is what you seem to be interested in.

Second, this type of problem comes down to the tradeoffs that you are willing to make. Multivariate analysis is likely to be more powerful than throwing away a type of outcome, but perhaps there are business reasons for only wanting to use one. You can evaluate those tradeoffs directly by resampling the data. For example, you could do repeated cross-validation, building models on subsets of the data while testing against the held-out observations, to see whether one or the other outcome is more reliable and what you lose by throwing away the other.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how to do MANOVA easily in matlab 2016a for my case?

Comment: @SydneyGirl I haven't used Matlab for years, so I can't help with that. Also, software-specific questions are off-topic on this site. You might find some help with Matlab on StackOverflow or on a Matlab help site. As Matlab is commercial, you should be able to get that type of specific help directly from MathWorks now that you know the type of analysis you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help!